# Como obter o script de criação das foreign keys de todo o banco de dados? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Gostaria de saber se existe algum comando que me retorna o script da criação das foreign keys no SQL server, assim como o comando sp_helptext me retorno o script de criação de views e stored procedures por exemplo.

Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec sp_helpconstraint <tabela>
```

retornará todas as dependencias que existe com essa tabela e a partir dessa tabela.

Comment: Gostaria de saber se existe um comando que já gera o script que pode ser diretamente executado, mas em todo caso acho que com o sp_helpconstraint já consigo montar o que preciso. Valeu

Comment: A propósito, marque a resposta como respondida.